# Can we send result of mysql query as return value of function using php?

Tags: php

I m creating function that process query and pass it's return result back. so I used following code:

```
function test(){
     $query = "select * from mytable where id=123";
     $data = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

     return $data;
}

$info = test();
```

is it possible and can i use $info to get values as $info[0],$info[1]..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing one vital part, returning the result of mysql_query() just returns a result pointer not the dataset. You should add `mysql_fetch_array`, `mysql_fetch_assoc` or `mysql_fetch_row`:

```
function test(){
     $query = "select * from mytable where id=123 LIMIT 1";
     $data = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
     $result = mysql_fetch_row($data);

     return $result;
}

$info = test();
```

now you can use $info[0], $info[1]. When using `mysql_fetch_assoc` you could use $info['fieldname'].

I also added LIMIT 1, since you're sending a long an ID, this probably is unique and after 1 result there is most likely nothing else to be returned.

Answer (score 2):

take a look at [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) function.

This function lets you iterate a query result which is a resource and turn each row into an array.Therefore you should use a while loop to get all rows in a resource;

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, however it is better in my experience to keep the database stuff encapsulated, so you don't expose MySQL resources outside of the database context that then further need `mysql_fetch_assoc()` and the like on them.

I would use PDO there, and return the results of `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`. That way, `$info` has the data it needs without needing to run further database functions on.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD');
    mysql_select_db('DB NAME', $link);

    function test()
    {
        $result = mysql_query("select * from wp_options");
        $data = array();

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $data[] = $row;
        }

        return $data;
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r(test());
    echo "</pre>";

    mysql_close($link);
?>
```